# Java version en Maven . ¿1.8 / 15?

Tags: java, maven

Hola no entiendo la diferencia entre poner versiones de java como la 17 / 8 etc que tiene números "elevados" y las versiones de 1.x  como la 1.7 o 1.8 . Es una pregunta muy básica quizá pero no encontré explicaciones en google.  Al mismo tiempo cuando uso Maven para ciertos proyectos tengo el siguiente código en el POM

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
```

el cual según veo es contrapuesto a

```
<properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
```

no pudiendo cambiar el primero por el segundo ya que no da resultado y simplemente sigue figurando 1.8 aunque modifique el POM.  No entiendo la diferencia y además no entiendo por qué en algunos proyectos me deja usar esa númeración y en otros no.

Comment: Hola. Las *versiones elevadas* que refieres son para proyectos basados en Spring, y esos números hacen referencia al [JDK de Java](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/), para esos proyectos basados en Spring. Para más detalles revisa [las explicaciones en Github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Spring-Framework-Versions), como [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54467287/5587982) en SO en inglés.

Comment: agrega las configuraciones de tu JDK/JDKs o no vamos a poder reproducir el problema